# Apache Camel JUnit test warnings

Tags: java, junit, apache-camel

I am trying to figure out how to get rid of a warning that is showing up in my JUnit tests. The test extends CamelTestSupport, but all of the test methods throw

```
WARN : Caught unhandled exception while processing ExchangedId:...

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: connectionFactory must be specified
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: can you post your entire unit test? likely just missing the JMS connectionFactory setup, see http://camel.apache.org/jms.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using JMS/AMQ, then you likely need to add this to setup your component/connectionFactory...

```
protected CamelContext createCamelContext() throws Exception {
    CamelContext camelContext = super.createCamelContext();
    String url = "vm://test-broker?broker.persistent=false&broker.useJmx=false";
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
    camelContext.addComponent("activemq", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));
    return camelContext;
}
```